# Excel vba match and display fields in separate labels

Tags: vba, excel

I am stuck with dynamically matching fields in excel (more than one) and then upon every match update the name of label as that match. This is the code i have found but i cant seem to edit it accordingly, it matches the fields but displays them in just one label with commas in between. I want with every match to show in a separate label. 
KR

```
Function MatchConcat(LookupValue, LookupRange As Range, ValueRange As Range)
    Dim lookArr()
    Dim valArr()
    Dim i As Long
    lookArr = LookupRange
    valArr = ValueRange
    For i = 1 To UBound(lookArr)
        If Len(lookArr(i, 1)) <> 0 Then
            If lookArr(i, 1) = LookupValue Then
            MatchConcat = MatchConcat & ", " & valArr(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MatchConcat = Mid(MatchConcat, 3, Len(MatchConcat) - 1)

End Function



   Dim var1 As String
var1 = MatchConcat(ComboBox3, Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A:A"), Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("B:B"))
Label18.Caption = var1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firstly, you will need to enable Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
>   You can do this by, in the VBE, going to Tools --> References --> Tick 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'.

You can add the matching items from the array to a dictionary. You can then loop through each item in the dictionary, and assign each item to a label.

You will need adjust the variable `i` to the start number of the label. `i` will then increment by 1 each time, assigning it's items to each label.

You have mentioned ComboBox and Labels; I've assumed you are referring to these within a UserForm. You will need to amend 'myUserForm' to the name of your actual UserForm.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MatchConcat()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim lookArr() As Variant, valArr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary, myItem As Variant
    Dim LookupValue As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LookupValue = myUserForm.ComboBox3.Value

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lookArr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))
        valArr = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lastRow, 2))
    End With

    If lastRow > 1 Then
        Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        For i = 1 To UBound(lookArr, 1)
            If lookArr(i, 1) = LookupValue Then
                dict.Item("Item" & valArr(i, 1)) = valArr(i, 1)
            End If
        Next i

        i = 18 'set to the name number of the first label
        For Each myItem In dict
            myUserForm.Controls("Label" & i).Caption = dict.Item(myItem)
            i = i + 1 ' increment i to line-up with labels numbers
        Next myItem
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** As per the question in the comments, you can include making the ComboBoxes visible by including the below in the code. Again, you have to make sure that the ComboBox number match the iteration number. The below would replace the bottom `For Each` from the above code.

```
i = 1 'set to the name number of the first label
For Each myItem In dict
    With myUserForm
        .Controls("Label" & i).Caption = dict.Item(myItem)
        .Controls("ComboBox" & i).Visible = True
        .Controls("ComboBox" & i & i).Visible = True
    End With
    i = i + 1 ' increment i to line-up with labels numbers
Next myItem
```

The first label would need to be called `Label1` and the first ComboBoxes would need to be called `ComboBox1` and `ComboBox11`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, 
one more thing Iturnet and sorry in advance for such dumb question because I am total newbie in this. I have a total of 20 combo boxes and upon every match of element, 2 would be visible.
e.g there were 3 matches, then 6 would show up, like in front of every label two comboboxes would become visible. I have total 10 labels and every label have 2 comboboxes infront of them so how can i make those two combo boxes visible upon every match. Could you please tell it in this code where. thanks

Comment: Function MatchConcat(LookupValue, LookupRange As Range, ValueRange As Range)
    Dim lookArr()
    Dim valArr()
    Dim i As Long
    lookArr = LookupRange
    valArr = ValueRange
    For i = 1 To UBound(lookArr)
        If Len(lookArr(i, 1)) <> 0 Then
            If lookArr(i, 1) = LookupValue Then
            MatchConcat = MatchConcat & ", " & valArr(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MatchConcat = Mid(MatchConcat, 3, Len(MatchConcat) - 1)

End Function

Comment: sorry for wrong formatting, can you please refer to the first code in question if its not legible

Comment: I've updated the answer with a reply to your question.